# SMPP Connection pooling and SmppSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring, spring-integration, smpp

I am using the int-smpp:outbound-gateway and providing a SmppSessionFactoryBean.
Up to now this has been a single tenant system but I am being asked to make this multi-tenanted.  So I believe I need to create a connection pool for the different tenant smpp connections. Is this something that is possible with smpp outbound gateway?

I was think in I could create a SmppSessionBeanFactory that would take in the SmppSessionFactoryBean and create an Smpp session if it did not exist or get it from a pool if it did exist.

Is there a better way to do this?

# UPDATE

This is essentially what I want to do

```
<int:channel id="smppSessionFactoryChannel"/>

<int:header-enricher id=""
    input-channel="smppSessionFactoryChannel" output-channel="smppOutBoundGatewayChannel">
    <int:header name="smppSession" ref="SmppSessionFactoryBeanFactory" method="getObject"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:channel id="smppOutBoundGatewayChannel"/>

<int-smpp:outbound-gateway id="smppOutBoundGateway"
    reply-channel="nullChannel" source-address=""
    request-channel="smppOutBoundGatewayChannel">
    <int-smpp:session value="#{headers[smppSession]}"/>
</int-smpp:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use session factory that uses a `ThreadLocal` to determine which session to use for a message (based on the tenant) - set the thread local upstream of the adapter, use it to get/create the session, remove it after completion.

That would not require any changes to the gateway itself.

Using the technique in the [dynamic ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) might be easier to implement too.

That mechanism has a small subordinate context for each tenant and a dynamic router to select which one to send the request to.